# Como elevar um número a uma potência sem usar a biblioteca math.h?

Tags: c++, matemática

Como eu posso elevar um número a uma potência sem usar a biblioteca `math.h`?

Exemplo:

```
potencia = x ^ 1/2;
```

Como faço isso em c++?

Comment: Por que não usar a função pronta da `libc`? Você está fazendo isso para um ambiente sem a `libc` ou é apenas um exercício para aprender como funciona?

Comment: Só para perceber: qual o porquê de não utilizar a biblioteca `math.h`?

Comment: Para expoentes inteiros é trivial, mas para qualquer outro caso isso é um problema de matemática/análise numérica, praticamente independente da linguagem.

Comment: Não é nada trivial, mas se isso ajudar, segue um link para uma implementação: http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como elevar número a potência fracionada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272357/como-elevar-n%c3%bamero-a-pot%c3%aancia-fracionada)

Answer (score 15):

Se o objetivo é aprender como a função funciona, uma boa forma é ler o código fonte de alguma implementação da `libc`, tomarei por exemplo a [**glibc**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/).

A função `powf` (chamada internamente de `__powf`) está definida no [**`/math/w_powf.c`**](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=math/w_powf.c;hb=HEAD). A operação dela se resume a chamar a `__ieee754_powf` que faz a operação real e depois lida com *edge cases*. Essa segunda está definida em [**`/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_powf.c`**](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_powf.c;hb=HEAD). Não é um código fácil de ler, mas pode valer o esforço. O interessante nesse código é que ele computa em tempo constante. Não há loops ou recursão.

Em uma outra implementação, a [**dietlibc**](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/), a função está no arquivo [**`/libm/pow.c`**](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/libm/pow.c). Ela tem uma otimização  para inteiros que calcula em um loop. O pow para não inteiros é calculado como `exp(log(mant)*expo)`, delegando a outras funções. A função `exp` e `log` são implementadas em assembly usando instruções apropriadas da FPU que fazem o cálculo em hardware. Ver [**`/i386/log.S`**](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/i386/log.S) e [**`/i386/exp.S`**](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/i386/exp.S).

Recomendo cuidado se pretende implementar sua própria versão de alguma dessas funções. Faça isso apenas se for realmente necessário (você estar em um ambiente extremamente limitado de recursos e não pode se dar ao luxo de incluir uma libc junto a sua aplicação). Escrever uma função equivalente pode ser muito interessante para estudos, mas não em produção.

Comment: Colocando de outra forma: implemente exp(x) e ln(x) usando séries infinitas e depois use a igualdade x^n = exp(n * ln(x))

Comment: @epx, a `exp(x)` é bastante simples de implementar com séries. Mas e quanto ao `log(x)`? Fiz alguns testes e não pude criar uma série convergente sem limitar o dominio. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Podemos dividir x por "e", por n vezes, até tornar |x|<1, usar a série de Taylor, e adicionar n ao resultado.

Comment: @epx O resultado não saiu tão preciso quanto eu gostaria. Fiz algo errado aqui? [**Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48dd8906fa39ca21)

Comment: Você poderia iterar até atingir uma precisão desejada (tanto em exp quanto em log), em vez de ter 11 passos fixos. É a primeira coisa que eu tentaria.

Comment: publiquei uma versão melhorada do seu código como resposta, funcionou razoavelmente bem, só precisaria testar com limites extremos e calibrar a precisão.

Answer (score 9):

Bem vindo ao mundo da matemática computacional onde várias funções como Pi, raiz quadrada, seno e coseno são implementadas como o somatórios de séries infinitas convergentes.

Existe uma questão igual no StackOverflow em inglês que vale a pena ler:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882706/how-can-i-write-a-power-function-myself

Também pode ser interessante visitar o wiki da fast inverse square root que fala da implementação performática (e menos precisa) do algoritmo.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Lembrando que todas esses algoritmos oferecem valores com algum grau de precisão, nunca um valor exato pois uma precisão "infinita" precisaria de processamento infinito e memória infinita.

Comment: Precisão "infinita" pode ser alcançada representando os valores na memória de forma simbólica. Por exemplo `sqrt(2)` é guardado como `sqrt(2)` e não como o resultado disso. Assim quando esse valor for elevado ao quadrado, o resultado é perfeitamente e exatamente `2`.

Comment: Estamos falando de somatório de séries infinitas convergentes não de matemática simbólica. Me atrevo a dizer que persitir símbolos dessa forma esta completamente fora do escopo da questão levantada pelo OP

Comment: É completamente fora sim. Estou apenas acrescentando.

Answer (score 8):

Minha tentativa, baseada no @Guilherme Bernal. Certamente tem problemas com valores extremos, acumulação de erros de arredondamento etc. etc. mas para valores "bem comportados" pareceu funcionar bem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double epsilon = 1e-15;

double myexp(double x) {
    double old_r = 0;
    double r = 1 + x;
    double div = 1;
    double i = 1;
    double m = x;
    while (fabs(1 - r / old_r) > epsilon) {
       div *= ++i;
       m *= x;
       old_r = r;
       r += m / div;
    }

    return r;
}

double mylog(double x) {
    static const double e = 2.718281828459045;
    int n = 0;
    while (fabs(x) >= 1) {
        x /= e;
        ++n;
    }

    x -= 1;
    double r = x;
    double m = x;
    double old_r = 0;
    double div = 1;
    double signal = 1;
    while (fabs(1 - r / old_r) > epsilon) {
       m *= x;
       old_r = r;
       signal *= -1;
       r += signal * m / ++div;
    }   
    return n+r;
}

int main() {
    printf("exp(1) = %.15f\n", exp(1));
    printf("exp(10) = %.15f\n", exp(10));
    printf("log(exp(10)) = %.15f\n", log(exp(10)));
    printf("sqrt(2) = %.15f\n", exp(0.5*log(2)));
    printf("--\n");
    printf("exp(1) = %.15f\n", myexp(1));
    printf("exp(10) = %.15f\n", myexp(10));
    printf("log(exp(10)) = %.15f\n", mylog(myexp(10)));
    printf("sqrt(2) = %.15f\n", myexp(0.5*mylog(2)));
}
```

Demonstração: [**Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/229c79acf88449b6)

```
exp(1) = 2.718281828459045
exp(10) = 22026.465794806717895
log(exp(10)) = 10.000000000000000
sqrt(2) = 1.414213562373095
--
exp(1) = 2.718281828459046
exp(10) = 22026.465794806710619
log(exp(10)) = 10.000000000000002
sqrt(2) = 1.414213562373096
```

Comment: Apenas melhorando a sua resposta, pois `sqrt(2) != 1.307`. Creio que vc quis dizer que `sqrt(2) = myexp(0.5*mylog(2))`

Comment: Verdade, a conta está errada. Teria de ser exp(0.5*ln(2)) para ser raiz de 2. Consertado programa e resultados.

Comment: não conheço essa fórmula para o cálculo de `log`. Eu [respondi uma questão idêntica à essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272376/64969) (não havia percebido que era duplicata, pensava serem apenas relacionadas) usando a definição de logaritmo neperiano através da integral de `1/x dx`

Comment: Mais fácil usar a série de Taylor, não?

Comment: Deve ser, se a pessoa souber como usar... Eu só conhecia o nome. Eu nunca tinha visto o que era uma série de Taylor até você mencionar

Comment: Se você se interessa pelo assunto, existe uma função log1p() que calcula o logaritmo de (x+1), porque a função log() e mesmo a minha mylog() perdem precisão quando x está perto de 1. Não é culpa da função, e sim de como números de ponto flutuante funcionam. https://www.johndcook.com/blog/cpp_log_one_plus_x/

Answer (score 6):

Unico modo de fazer isso é pela aproximação

```
(1+x)^(1/2) ~ 1 + x/2
```

quando x é muito pequeno, ou criando uma rotina para a série completa

```
(1+x)^(1/2) = 1 + x/2 - 3x/4 + 15x/8 - ...
```

coisa que a função sqrt() já faz eficientemente. Então, os únicos motivos para não usá-la é se você estiver estudando computação numérica ou quer criar algum algoritmo melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Pense em como você faria isso em uma prova de matemática. `x^(1/2)` equivale a `sqrt(x)`. Com isso em mente, o restante da implementação é bem tranquilo.

Observação: conforme lembrado, de fato `x^(1/2)` equivale a `sqrt(x)` e não a `1/x^2`, como os colegas me lembraram. A implementação de uma raiz quadrada é um pouco mais complicada do que eu havia planejado, mas continua valendo a intenção da resposta inicial – basta ver como você faria a implementação (ou melhor, o algoritmo).

Comment: Na verdade, `x^(1/2)` = `sqrt(x)`

Comment: `x^(1/2)` **NÃO** é `1/(x^2)`. Isso seria `x^(-2)`.

Comment: Ate mesmo `sqrt` é não trivial de ser implementado. E me parece que o expoente `1/2` foi apenas um exemplo, ele estaria interessado em `a^b`, podendo ambos ser não inteiros.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, o programa com a função ficará assim:

```
float paw (float x, float y);

main()
{

float a, b, res;

    printf("Entre com o base:");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("\n\nEntre com o expoente:");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    res= paw(a,b);
    printf("O resultado sera:%f\n\n", res);
    system("pause");


}

float paw ( float x, float y)

{

float i;

float a;

if(y== 0 && x!=0)

return 1;

else if(y>=0)

{

a=1;

for( i=0 ; i<=y-1 ; i++)

a = x*a;

return a;

}
else

{

y = -1*y;

a=1;

for( i=0 ; i<=y-1 ; i++)

a = x*a;

a = 1.0/a;

return a;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O mais simples possível
sem a biblioteca math.h

```
//Tomás Louraco 19/02/18
//Programa que escreve a potencia
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
int b, a, i, c=1;
cout << "\t\tIntroduza o valor de A : ";
cin >> a;
cout << "\t\tIntroduza o expoente : ";
cin >> b;
for (i=0;i<=b;i++)
{
c=c*a;
}
cout << "\n\n\n\t\tResultado : " << c;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Só que a questão é pegar justamente casos não inteiros, como `0.5`

Answer (score -1):

Imagino que seja mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int b,c,d,n,x,y,z;
double p;
printf("Lembrando que: base ^ (numerador/denominador) = potencia\n\n"); //Linha opcional
printf("Digite o valor da base: ");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("Digite o numerador da fracao do expoente: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Digite o denominador da fracao do expoente: ");
scanf("%d",&d);
x=1;
z=n;
while (z>0)
{
    z=z-1;
    x=x*b;
}
p=0;
y=0;
while (y<x)
{
    p=p+0.00001;
    c=0;
    y=1;
    while (c<d)
    {
        c=c+1;
        y=y*p;
    }
}
printf("\n\nPotencia: %d ^ (%d/%d) = %.4lf",b,n,d,p);
getchar();
}
```