# Como elevar número a potência fracionada?

Tags: c++, matemática

Gostaria de saber como elevar um número a uma potência fracionada, por exemplo `2^2.5`, `3^0.7` ?

Para números inteiros positivos funciona mais ou menos assim :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int exp=4,num=2,soma=1;

    for(int i=1;i<=exp;i++){
        soma=soma*num;
    }
    cout << "o resultado eh  " << soma << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Mas como seria para números fracionários ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como elevar um número a uma potência sem usar a biblioteca math.h?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5250/como-elevar-um-n%c3%bamero-a-uma-pot%c3%aancia-sem-usar-a-biblioteca-math-h)

Comment: @VictorStafusa, eu creio que as respostas na outra pergunta estão superficiais demais. Eu fiz a marcação inversa (aquela como duplicata desta), pois creio que minha resposta dá mais profundidade (apesar de ter espaço para **muito** mais) no porquê da exponenciação de números de ponto flutuante ser assim.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não quer usar a biblioteca matemática e o método `pow`? Pois bem, vamos à definição crua.

O [@Phelipe comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272357/como-elevar-n%c3%bamero-a-pot%c3%aancia-fracionada#comment557427_272358) sobre uma [fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5282/64969) muito interessante de como calcular potenciação. Vamos às definições vistas no ensino médio e então entramos em assunto de séries convergentes com funções formadas pela soma infinita de polinômios.

### Exponenciação natural

> A partir de agora, vamos indicar em texto a operação na forma `b^n`, que quer dizer:
>
> - `b` é a base da exponenciação
> - `^` é o operador da exponenciação
> - `n` é o expoente
>
> Por questão de simplicidade e para evitar complexos, mantenhamos `b` estritamente positivo e diferente de 1.
>
> **ATENÇÃO**
>
> Abaixo eu vou pular diversos passos formais para focar no entendimento um pouco mais intuitivo da questão. Então, se você estiver sentindo falta de algum formalismo ou que eu pulei rapidamente para uma conclusão sem ter todas as ferramentas necessárias para tal conclusão, não me crucifique. Tentarei colocar referências para uma demonstração correta.

A exponenciação natural é igual direta ao ponto (desconsidere o 0 como natural agora). O expoente indica quantas vezes você deve multiplicar a base no seguinte algoritmo:

1. se `n == 1`, retorne `b`
2. caso contrário, retorne `b * b^(n-1)`

Essa definição, no entanto, só nos fornece resultados para `n` natural. Para o seu caso, `n` como ponto flutuante (que é um subconjunto dos racionais), precisamos ir além. Precisamos por em cheque algumas questões:

1. números negativos
2. `n` nulo/zero
3. números fracionados

Vamos incluir os números inteiros `<= 0`?

### Exponenciação inteira

O que acontece quando conhecemos a potência de uma determinada base, e precisamos pegar o número logo abaixo dela?

Pela definição, conhecemos o valor de `b^(n+1)` e precisamos chegar em `b^n`. Podemos ignorar totalmente o valor de `b^(n+1)` e fazer `n` multiplicações ou, se formos espertos, fazer apenas uma única divisão. Como? Analisando a definição, óbvio.

Nós sabemos pela definição recursiva que `b^(n+1) = b*b^n` para todo `n` natural. Então a maneira com menos operações para obter `b^n` é fazer `b^n = b^(n+1)/b`.

Isso faz sentido, pois é como se tirássemos uma vez o fator `b` da jogada. Então, uma generalização é dizer que `1/b = b^-1`. Então, o que seria `(1/b)^4`? Seria `1/b * 1/b * 1/b * 1/b` a partir da definição da exponenciação natural, o que dá sinais de que estamos no caminho correto.

Com isso incluímos os inteiros negativos. E para `n == 0`? Bem, podemos chegar nele fazendo o seguinte pensamento:

Podemos extrapolar que `b^n * b == b^(n+1)` é sempre verdade. Então, para `n == 0`, temos que `b^0 * b == b^(0+1) == b^1`. Por definição, `b^1 == b`. Podemos tratar `b^0` como uma incógnita, portanto `b^0 == b/b == 1`.

Conseguimos estender a exponenciação natural para a exponenciação inteira. Para estender para os racionais, antes gostaria de apresentar a operação inversa.

### Logaritmicando

O logaritmo é a operação inversa da exponenciação. Isso significa que, dados `b` e `b^n`, é possível se obter qual seria esse `n`. Como que o logaritmo é definido? Bem, vamos a notação:

```
log_b(x) = n
```

Aqui estamos pergunta qual seria o expoente `n` tal que a base `b` elevando a `n` resultasse no operando `x`, portanto `x = b^n`. Existe uma base muito especial nos logaritmos que é o número de Euler [`e`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). Ele é tão importante que tem até mesmo notação própria:

```
ln(x) = log_e(x)
```

> As vezes fontes dizem que esse `ln` é **logaritmo natural**, outras que é **logaritmo de Napier**/**logaritmo neperiano** (neperiano nesse caso é referente a Napier). Eu gosto da segunda forma de chamar porque lembra do matemática [Napier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Napier) que fez a primeira referência a essa constante, mesmo que de maneira tortuosa

Com essa notação e também com o fato de que `ln(x)` é o inverso de `e^x`, então temos que `e^(ln(x)) == x`.

Uma outra propriedade de um logaritmo é que `ln(b^c) == c*ln(b)`, dado que:

- qualquer `c`
- `b` real positivo diferente de 1.

Mas em que isso me ajuda? Porque ambas as funções unários de exponenciação por `e` e logaritmo são definidas matematicamente.

### `e^x`

A função exponencial é definida por um [limite de um somatório](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition):

[image: exponencial como soma infinita]

Podemos usar somas infinitas no computador? Por incrível que pareça, sim, podemos, mas desde que ela seja **convergente**.

> Mesmo assim, estamos assumindo um risco de perder precisão. Eu dou um exemplo de como incorrer na perda de precisão ao calcular 30% de imposto sobre a venda de 72 itens a 574.75 [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219465/64969). Em outra nota eu discorro sobre a perda de precisão, pois depende do método usado

Para começar a responder, primeiro precisamos verificar se essa [série infinita converge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series). A definição formal é muito chata, mas podemos usar algo derivado dela para chegar em algo mais fácil de manusear.

Pegue uma série infinita `S`. Seja `Sn` o n-ésimo termo da série. Seja `f(n) = |Sn|` uma função dos inteiros nos reais. Se `f` for decrescente para todo `x >= N`, então `S` converge.

Ok, e qual o termo `Sn` para o exponencial? É `x^n/n!` (que é um número não negativo). Então precisamos encontrar algum valor para `n` tal que `S_(n+1) < Sn`. E depois demonstrar que isso é válido para qualquer valor acima de `n+1`. Fácil, né?

No primeiro passo, vamos ver o que acontece com `Sx` (para um `x` inteiro)? Temos exatamente `x^x/x!`. Pela definição de fatorial temos que `x! == x * (x-1)!`. Pela definição de exponenciação, temos que `x^x == x^(x-1) * x`. Daí:

```
x^x/x!
x*x^(x-1) / x * (x-1)!
(x/x)  *  (x^(x-1)/(x-1)!)
1 * x^(x-1)/(x-1)!
```

Olha só, que coincidência! `Sx == 1*S_(x-1)`. E se consinuarmos a aumentar? Digamos, para `S_(x+1)`:

```
x^(x+1) / (x+1)!
x * x^x / (x+1) * x!
(x^x/x!) * (x/x+1)
Sx * (x/x+1)
```

Como `x/x+1` é menor do que 1, temos que multiplicamos por um valor menor do que 1. Para `x+2`, vamos pegar `S_(x+1)` e multiplicar por `x/x+2`, que é menor do que `x/x+1`. Portanto, temos que, para `n >= x`, a função `f(n) = Sn` se torna decrescente. Então converge.

E se tivermos um `x` não inteiro? Um `x` real? Bem, nesse caso, podemos extrapolar esse pensamento para pegar `y` o primeiro inteiro menor do que `x`. O nosso número de corte, para o qual `f(n)` se torna decrescente, é `y` (porque `x/y > 1` e `x/y+1 < 1`, portanto se tornando decrescente a partir desse ponto).

Agora que temos uma série convergente, como fazer essa soma? A grosso modo, até a soma ter importância no nosso ponto flutuante.

### Soma importante com ponto flutuante

Tomemos um número qualquer, `a`. Ele é um número pertencente ao conjunto de números de mantissa finita de n dígitos (assim como o [IEEE754 também](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats), para 24 bits).

> Vou assumir aqui que a mantissa é 4 e estamos falando de dígitos na base 10, mas não é difícil extrapolar.

Isso significa que `a` está no seguinte formato:

```
x.yzk * 10^e
```

Um valor possível para `a`, portanto, seria:

```
6.473 * 10^7
```

O que acontece se somarmos com um número com expoente `6` (`7-1`)? Vamos pegar um exemplo em que não ocorra nenhum *carry* por simplicidade:

```
6.473 * 10^7   +
5.112 * 10^6
-----------------
6.473 * 10^7   +
0.5112 * 10^7
-----------------
6.9842 * 10^7
```

Porém, como `2` é o quinto dígito, ele não está mais representável em um número de mantissa fixa. Portanto não é possível distinguir entre essa soma de cima com está outra soma:

```
6.473 * 10^7   +
5.110 * 10^6
-----------------
6.473 * 10^7   +
0.5110 * 10^7
-----------------
6.9840 * 10^7
```

Isso significa que o valor do dígito menos significativo se tornou irrelevante. Inclusive, se pegarmos um número `y = 0.009 * 10^6` e fizermos `s = a+y`, o valor de `s` será `s == a`.

Como não estamos falando da nossa aritmética de todo dia, tem algumas coisas que vale a pena falar. A soma, por exemplo, **não é associativa**. Vamos provar isso?

Sabemos que `a+y == a` por conta do passo anterior. Isso significa, também, que:

```
a == a+y
a == (a+y)+y
a == ((a+y)+y)+y
...
```

E por aí vai. Porém, e se agruparmos `y` de outra maneira? Por exemplo, somemos assim:

```
a + (y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y)
```

Ora, aqui somamos `a` com `y*10`. O que isso significa? Que o dígito de `y` agora se torna relevante. Então `a + (y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y+y) > a`.

Numa série infinita convergente, nos interessa fazer a soma de `Sn` para índices crescentes. Isso significa que, enquanto `Sn + S_(n+1) > Sn`, a soma tem relevância e devemos continuar. Porém, se `Sn + S_(n+1) == Sn`, então chegamos a um ponto em que os valores novos obtidos se tornam irrelevantes.

Para somar os termos de `f(x)` que tem relevância, podemos fazer assim:

```
int n = 0;
double sum = 0;
while (sum + f(n) > sum) {
    sum += f(n);
    n++;
}
```

> Esse algoritmo pode ser otimizado, principalmente se soubermos o comportamento de `f(x+1)` em relação a `f(x)` (mas também pode ser absurdamente otimizado sem saber disso), mas a ideia geral é essa.

### `ln(x)`

Essa é a função que define o logaritmo natural de um número:

[image: fórmula de logaritmo neperiano de um número através de uma integral]

Podemos usar alguns métodos matemáticos distintos para calcular a integral, o meu favorito é o [método dos trapézios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule). Veja [aqui para uma implementação JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279410/64969).

### Pondo tudo junto

Para calcular tudo, conforme a [resposta indicado pelo @Phelipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5282/64969), basta fazermos `e^(ln(b)*n)`.

Então, primeiramente, calculamos o valor de `ln(b)` usando o método dos trapézios para calcular a integral. Então, multiplicamos esse resultado por `n`, seja `n` um número qualquer. Sobre o resultado dessa multiplicação, aplicamos o resultado então na série infinita que descreve a exponenciação, somando seus termos individualmente até que encontremos um índice `i` qualquer tal que somar `Si` seja irrelevante para a precisão da mantissa fixa usada: `somatorio_ateh_i + Si == somatorio_ateh_i`.

Vale ressaltar que o método dos trapézios e a soma da série infinita são extremamente ineficientes.

## Conclusão

Foi uma bela brincadeira matemática, mas se precisar usar exponenciação de dois números não inteiros... Faça com operações da **biblioteca padrão**, elas lhe pouparão problemas de performance. Igual ao que o [@Phelipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272357/como-elevar-n%c3%bamero-a-pot%c3%aancia-fracionada/272376#comment557428_272358) e o [@epx](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272357/como-elevar-n%c3%bamero-a-pot%c3%aancia-fracionada/272376?noredirect=1#comment585232_272376) comentaram.

Comment: Ótima resposta. Queria entender como funcionava esse cálculo com pontos flutuantes.

Comment: Vou substituir por um exemplo concreto. Talvez ajude. De toda sorte, [numa das respostas que citei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219465/64969) tem referência a alguns vídeos no YT (em inglês) que ajudam a entender como se dão essas operações

Comment: @Beto , mudei o exemplo da soma de ponto flutuante para algo concreto. Pode ajudar no entendimento. Também estou me precavendo de possível arredondamento que poderia ser feito aí arredondar o número antes de somar, que eu desconsiderava

Comment: Ok. Ficou melhor para entender, obrigado.

Comment: E tem quem acha que calcular `pow(x, y)` só adiciona o custo de uma chamada de função a mais no código :D

Comment: @Beto, mais referência no assunto de manipulação de números de ponto flutuante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/64969

Comment: Usar pow() da biblioteca pode ser bom porque talvez use instruções otimizadas do processador.

Comment: @epx, pode ser bom? Pois eu tenho certeza que será melhor. A ideia da resposta era que partisse dessa premissa (já descrita na primeira linha): "Não quer usar a biblioteca matemática e o método `pow`?" Acho que vou por uma conclusão no final da resposta indicando que o `pow` é o melhor dos casos quase sempre

Comment: Verdade, só mencionei pro caso de alguém achar que descobriu a pólvora fazendo isso "na mão".

Answer (score 3):

Você já está usando a biblioteca matemática que trás diversas funções para trabalhar com cálculos matemáticos. Para fazer a potenciação você pode usar a função `pow`

Segue um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float exp=4.9,num=2.0;
    cout << "o resultado eh  " << pow(num,exp) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Caso queira saber mais você pode acessar esse [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/):

Comment: Queria saber como fazer isso na mão mesmo. Para entender o funcionamento na programação.

Comment: Você pode olhar aqui então. Tem desde o algorítimo até uma explicação de como a função pow funciona. 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5250/como-elevar-um-n%C3%BAmero-a-uma-pot%C3%AAncia-sem-usar-a-biblioteca-math-h

Comment: Lembrando que não é recomendável você usar suas próprias funções para fazer esse tipo de cálculo. As funções existentes são as mais otimizadas possíveis e testadas por um grande número de pessoas.